# how to get data from a base64 encoding of a .pptx file in javascript

Tags: javascript, base64, office-js

I get data from a server of the .pptx file in base64 encoding now i would like to get the text that is present inside the base64 data.

Is there any third party java script library to do this especially scanning in base64 code rather than taking the file path and i would like insert these strings into a power point using office js.

Client side would be preferred.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems that what you need is a JavaScript decoder for base64 files, there are many projects in Github Doing this, for instance here is one https://github.com/mathiasbynens/base64.

That said, I am not sure about your scenario, and what types of files are been base64-encoded. Base64 at the end of the day is a text "representation" of *usually* a binary file, like an image or a compressed zip file. I wonder if once you decode it you will get what you expect. And if you are expecting text, i wonder why your service is even encoding it like this.

Anyways... once you have whatever text you want to insert, you can use the setSelectedDataAsync method of our Office.js in PPT to write it in your presentation's active selection.   https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.setselecteddataasync